# Vite + React: --host to external mobile display doesn't load, gets timeout

Tags: server, localhost, vite, host

I try to expose my `localhost` environment in a Vite (React) project to my mobile phone. I have a package.json with the following script:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "host": "vite --host 192.168.1.***",
}
```

When I run "host" the project gets fired up nicely. Both the `localhost` and the Network address work on desktop. I cannot get the mobile address to work (Android, Chrome browser) when I visit the address there (both `http` and `https`).

It keeps loading until it gets a timeout ('Server does not respond').

I tried to disable the firewall, checked the browser settings, checked that the networks on both devices are the same, tried to add my IP4 address to the package.json script, but no luck. Any ideas are appreciated.